# Have MS Access and am trying to Link to data in a file with the extension .PGDB

Tags: ms-access

I'm not positive this is the file I want. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks. Mark

Comment: What program created taht file?

Comment: What **do** you know about whatever it is you're trying to link to? Besides that you're not sure that its extension should be "PGDB".

Comment: I have a restaurant with a POS system called SoftTouch. I want to attach to the database files used by softtouch. I've looked through all the SoftTouch directories and have found only this file named POS.PGDB that looks like it could be the main data file. It's size is 112,552 Kb.

Comment: I do not know what program created the PGDB file

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out:

- if the `.PGDB` file is actually the database file you're looking for
- what kind of database this is

The best way to find that out would be to contact the manufacturer of your POS system, as suggested by Tony in his comment.

But even if it *is* the database file, unfortunately you can't assume that you can just open it in Access and be done. Access is not able to open every database format under the sun.
Maybe it will really work, if there's an [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC) or [OLE DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB) provider for `.PDGB`.

If you can't open it with Access...well, it depends on what kind of database this is.
If it's a "real" database format by some vendor (and not some self-baked in-house solution by the software company that made the POS system), there are probably some database management tools (like [Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) for MS SQL databases, or the [MySQL Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench) for MySQL databases) available, which you can use to browse the database.